# Fetching all senders' emails in imaplib

Tags: imaplib

With this I get a list of email from particular senders:

```
import email
import imaplib
username = "TBD"
pw = "TBD"
suka = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")
suka.login(username, pw)
suka.select("INBOX")
key = 'FROM'
value = 'TBD' 
_, data = suka.search(None, key, value)
mail_id_list = data[0].split()
msgs = []
```

But what if need to skip giving a sender "FROM", but want to get a list of just all messages in the inbox. Something like:
key = 'FROM'
value = any.
I don't see such possibility in the lib docs, but suppose such a function should exist. Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
_, data = suka.search(None, "ALL")
```

Your full code will look like this:

```
import email
import imaplib
username = "TBD"
pw = "TBD"
suka = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")
suka.login(username, pw)
suka.select("INBOX")
_, data = suka.search(None, "ALL")
mail_id_list = data[0].split()
msgs = []
```

Updated

```
username = "TBD"
pw = "TBD"
suka = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")
suka.login(username, pw)
suka.select("INBOX")

# Search for all messages in the inbox
_, data = suka.search(None, "ALL")
mail_id_list = data[0].split()

# Loop through the message IDs and retrieve the message contents
for mail_id in mail_id_list:
    _, message_data = suka.fetch(mail_id, "(RFC822)")
    message = email.message_from_bytes(message_data[0][1])
    msgs.append(message)
```

Comment: many thanks. But the msgs list is empty after the code

Comment: @LevdarArmenia apologies for the incomplete code. I have update the code to reflect the changes